For stream processing plugin in Apache IoTDB, how to start the service after generating in resource directory?
I am learning the new stream processing component in Apache IoTDB. I did not understand how to place a custom stream processing plugin in the so-called resource directory? Where is the plugin https resource address that needed to be set before using the plugin configured? Anyone can clarify the steps that I need to do?

If I understand correctly, you are talking about setting up a service of stream processing in Apache IoTDB. For example, mark your plugin as example, then the creation statement of this data processing plug-in is: CREATE PIPEPLUGIN example AS 'edu.tsinghua.iotdb.pipe.ExampleProcessor' USING URI '<https://example.com:8080/iotdb/pipe-plugin.jar>'. You can change the directory and link as you want.
